# Creating an event handler or a different event then the keydown on wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, keyevent

I mean that I need to create an event of keydown that gets `Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e` and not `Object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyboardEventArgs e`.

The code I try:

```
this.KeyDown = MainWindow_KeyDown;
    }
    public new event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
    public delegate void KeyEventHandler(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e);
    void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.N && e.Control)
            StartNewGame();
    }
```

How can I make this event?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. If you want to receive Windows Forms events, you need to use a Windows Forms form, not a WPF window.

The far more interesting question is: what are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can help you with implementing in WPF what you're trying to implement?

Comment: I wanted to crate a newgame() every time some one presses Ctrl + N 
it should be easy I just wanted to know if I could use the System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs for it.

Comment: No you can't. You need to use the WPF equivalent.